# postgresql 8.4 original config files (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

Where can I find the original postgresql 8.4 config files for ubuntu (/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/*)?

Upgraded ubuntu to version 9.10. which included upgrading postgresql from 8.3 to 8.4

dir with config files is empty (/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/)

Completely removed and then reinstalled all ubuntu postgres packages (server, client, admin), but that didn't reinstall/populate the config files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you didn't completely remove the packages, or the configs would have been restored.  Make sure you remove the `common` package as well, as well as using the `--purge` option to aptitude.

Comment: womble: thanks, this worked. Although I did not specified it above I had also removed/reinstalled the common pkgs.  The --purge must have done it since I had not used that option before.

Comment: waiting for enough reputation to be able to "uptick" (this was my first question)